# Phase shift of trigonometric functions.

Tags: trigonometry

While studying for my calc 1 exam, I've stumbled across something I always knew but never thought about and now I cannot figure out the reason as to why it is the way it is.

Suppose a function
$$\sin(x)$$
[image]

Now contract it
$$\sin(2x)$$
[image]

Now add a little phase shift
$$\sin(2x+\pi)$$
[image]

My intuition (which is obviously wrong) tells me that this graph should be looking different. It is contracted two times ($2x$) and then it should be moved by $\pi$. This, however, would make the graph look just the same as the $\sin(2x)$ graph, as moving the graph of $\sin(2x)$ by $\pi$ on the x-axis would make it start at the same place. So why do we calculate the phase shift by dividing the $\pi$ by $2$? I know the formula, I just need to find a way to change the intuition I have now.

Comment: Does viewing the function in the form $\sin(2(x+\pi/2))$ correct your intuition?

Comment: @qcpz So basically it's a graph of $\sin(x+\pi/2)$ but contracted two times? That would make sense, I think it clicked.

Comment: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/5614/372